# Find bit masks for number positions

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, bit-manipulation, bit

I'm trying to work out a logic for a game (in Flash). In one part, given the following row:

`_ _ * _ _ __ *`

I need to find if all the spaces between the `*`'s are empty (Non-empty values other than * can occur in the row). *This operation is done quite frequently*.
I was wondering if I could use bit representations of rows to achieve this, instead of looping through and checking the intermediate positions.

For a row `_ _ * _ _ _ *` represented as `xx1xxx1` (`x` = 1 or 0), I could AND it with `0001110` so that if the answer is `0000000`, the intermediate positions are empty.

The question here is, of course, how to find this second map (`0001110` above) using bit operations (in Flash AS2)? (Map (1,4) -> 0110, (1,3) -> 0100 etc)
Or is looping through the intermediate positions just the better choice?

Comment: Not sure, but do you know the positions of the bits surrounding the bits you are interested in? Or is it the leftmost and rightmost 1, like `001xxx1`?

Comment: Yes, I know the positions. That's what I meant by Map(1,4), Map(1,3) etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by shifting some bits.

```
var bits:int = 0x7F; // 7 bits
var mask:int = ((bits >> (bits - end)) << start) & bits;
```

I'm not sure how you count to the positions, in the example it seems like you did it from the left, starting with a one - I'm going to count from the right, starting with zero, which is more common I guess. So the value of `start` is the position of the first `1` (from the right, counting up from zero) and `end` the position of the leftmost `1`.

An example of how it works in detail:

```
// row:          xx1xxx1
// desired mask: 0001110
//               the sequence of ones in the mask starts at 1, ends at 3

bits = 0x7F;        // 1111111
mask = bits >> 4;   // 0000111
mask = mask << 1;   // 0001110
```

Another way of describing this: `bits-(end+1)` is the amount of zeroes on the left and `start` is the amount of zeroes on the right of the sequence of ones.